# Detecting a coil is fully energized

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, current-limiting

I'm working on customized ignition system and want to implement the final stage as robust as possible.
The ECU (Engine Control Unit) provides TTL level control signal to drive ignition system. The duty cycle of that signal depends on engine's speed (RPM).
Ignition coil must be energized in order to provide spark. After it is energized it starts heating and can be broken.

[image: Coil current]

The ECU can't control the current and different coils can be used in amateur autosport engines.
So ignition driver should control the current. Firstly I wanted to use MC33812 IGBT ignition driver. In case of overcurrent it closes IGBT. This produces early spark as the coil discharges. It can broke the engine at high RPM. And I found no ignition driver that can work as Pick'n'Hold driver.
So I selected IRGB14C40 IGBT with TTL gate level. I decided to use ACS712 current sense IC. It has proportional voltage output. Add Voltage-to-PWM IC, like TL494 and drive IGBT's gate in case of overcurrent.
And of course PWM should work inversely and keep current steady.
Or may be I should use inverted op-amp comparator and compare ACS712 output with voltage source. When it close gate current drops, and if op-amp and ACS712 are fast - current flow starts again and prevent the coil from discarge. This will works like PWM may be

simplified block-scheme

[image: Driver]

Input frequency is about 20kHz at max. I'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: There is a lot of context that you have and we don't - including the schematic. Is it a magneto coil? What is the driver driving? What do you have to hold and when is the right moment? And we don't know what the scope traces represent either. So I'll be quite surprised if anyone can answer the question in its current form.

Comment: I rewrite the question, I hope I made it more clear

Comment: What is the current limit value?

Comment: about 7A at 14.7V

Comment: Look up the Megasquirt project, they have been driving ignition coils with IGBT's for years, I think Bosch BIP373 are the device of choice. Or you could use OE coils with built-in ignitor/driver circuits as fitted to many cars these days and have the hard work done for you.

Comment: I don't understand what the question was. Were you just looking for general thoughts on your plan? Anyhow, the circuit you have shown won't work. Turning the mosfet off will result in an inductor voltage surge, which will probably fry the mosfet. Seeing as you need more voltage than the would 12V battery can supply, I recommend a boost converter topology, which you could use for PWM-current conversion. Ensuring loop stability could be difficult- you might need some circuit simulation/trials there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a IC? Several companies have made these for years.  They control the coil charging etc for you and no software!  ST has them listed under: Ignition Controllers and Drivers.

Comment: My God, it seems that ST is the only one who implemented it: "If the input signal from the microcontroller happens to remain high, the device protects itself against overheating by forcing collector current to smoothly decrease (low voltage clamp feature) to avoid undesired spark.". I was so dissapointed by other companies that didn't checked ST.    VB526SP-E seems to be perfect choice. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Other companies make them but they are custom IC's and not available to others. The algorithm used is customer dependent.